# Using VGG16, 2.0 "Loss" not decreasing, something with prepreat data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, kaggle

I'm trying to create model for facial emotion recognition.
My dataset is from "kaggle face recognition" (or sth like this).
Set is in *.csv file emotion+pixels (as a string eg. "3, pixel pixel pixel...") and I'm preprocessing it by this method:

```
def resizeImages(x):
    x = x.astype('float32')
    x = x / 255.0
    return x

def loadData():
    print("Data loading START")
    rawData = pd.read_csv("../data/data.csv")
    pixels = rawData['pixels'].tolist()
    images = []
    for each in pixels:
        image = [int(pixel) for pixel in each.split()]
        image = np.asarray(image).reshape(width, height)
        images.append(image.astype('float32'))
    images = np.asarray(images)
    images = np.expand_dims(images, -1)
    images = np.repeat(images, 3, axis=3)
    emotions = pd.get_dummies(rawData['emotion'])
    print(emotions)
    images = resizeImages(images)
    print("Data loading DONE")
    return images, emotions
```

My model is made like this:

```
#Constants
width, height, depth = 48, 48, 3
numOfClasses = 7
epochs = 10
batch_size = 50

#Loading Data
from Model.DataProcess import loadData
pixels, emotions = loadData()

#Spliting Data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest  = train_test_split(pixels, emotions, test_size = 0.2)

#Loading VGG16 Model
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
vgg16model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',
                 input_shape=(width, height, depth), pooling='avg')

#Frezzing layers at VGG16 model - not trainable
for layer in vgg16model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

#Creating final classifier
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dropout, Dense

myModel = Sequential([
    vgg16model,
    Dense(256, input_shape=(512,), activation="relu"),
    Dense(256, input_shape=(256,), activation="relu"),
    Dropout(0.25),
    Dense(128, input_shape=(256,)),
    Dense(output_dim=numOfClasses, activation="softmax")
])

myModel.summary()

#Creating optimizer
from keras.optimizers import Adamax
adamax = Adamax()

myModel.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                   optimizer=adamax,
                   metrics=['accuracy'])


#Fiting model
history = myModel.fit(
    xtrain, ytrain,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=(xtest, ytest),
    callbacks = callbacks
)
```

Am I doing something wrong, couse after a bunch op epchos my loss is still about 1.5 and accuracy is nearly 0.4

Comment: why do you need to use so many FC layers after VGG? It's probably making your model vegetable. Start with a VGG + single FC and Softmax

Comment: I'm not sure if get it, i removed all layers. The only one that i left is '''Dense(output_dim=numOfClasses, activation="softmax")''' Did you mean it?